# Failed to Inject Generic Dependency C#

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core

I'm trying to create a base DbContext to use in a generic repository.

The object is to have a centralized base repository and service to use on a micro-services environment, but each service must pass the type of the determined dbContext to use for the queries.

Already tried to chance the TContext type from ApiDbContext to a pure DbContext, no success.

The API is running over .NET Core 2.2 with EFCore 2.2.6

The code is as follow

Repository implementation

```
public class Repository<TContext> : IDisposable, IRepository<TContext>
        where TContext : ApiDbContext, new()
```

Repository Interface

```
public interface IRepository<TContext> : IDisposable where TContext : ApiDbContext
```

ApiDbContext

```
public class ApiDbContext : DbContext
{
    private static readonly bool[] _migrated = { false };
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public ApiDbContext()
    {

    }

    public ApiDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApiDbContext> options, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
            : base(options)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        Database.SetCommandTimeout(300);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        new AuditConfiguration(modelBuilder.Entity<Audit>());

        foreach (IMutableForeignKey relationship in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes().SelectMany(e => e.GetForeignKeys()))
        {
            relationship.DeleteBehavior = DeleteBehavior.Restrict;
        }

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    protected static DbContextOptions<T> ChangeOptionsType<T>(DbContextOptions options) where T : DbContext
    {
        var sqlExt = options.Extensions.FirstOrDefault(e => e is SqlServerOptionsExtension);

        if (sqlExt == null)
            throw (new Exception("Failed to retrieve SQL connection string for base Context"));

        return new DbContextOptionsBuilder<T>()
                    .UseSqlServer(((SqlServerOptionsExtension)sqlExt).ConnectionString)
                    .Options;
    }
}
```

AuthDbContext

```
public class AuthDbContext : ApiDbContext
{
    public AuthDbContext(DbContextOptions<AuthDbContext> options, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor) 
        : base(ChangeOptionsType<ApiDbContext>(options), httpContextAccessor)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        new UserConfiguration(modelBuilder.Entity<User>());

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Exception

> TypeLoadException: GenericArguments[0], 'Company.Project.Auth.Infrastructure.Data.AuthDbContext', on 'Company.Project.Common._Bases.Infrastructure.Repository`1[TContext]' violates the constraint of type parameter 'TContext'.

Code that throws the exception (At repository injection)

```
public class Service<T, TContext> : IService<T>
   where T : BaseEntity
    where TContext : ApiDbContext
{
    protected IRepository<TContext> _repository { get; set; }

    public Service(IServiceProvider provider)
    {
        _repository = provider.GetService(typeof(IRepository<TContext>)) as IRepository<TContext>;
    }
}
```

DependencyInjection

```
public static void Resolve<T>(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration Configuration) where T : DbContext
        {
            services.AddDbContext<T>(options =>
               options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString(Configuration["StartupConfig:DefaultConnectionString"]),
                   b => b.MigrationsAssembly(Configuration["StartupConfig:MigrationAssembly"])
                   .UseRowNumberForPaging()));

            services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
            services.AddTransient(typeof(IService<>), typeof(Service<,>));
            services.AddTransient(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Repository<>));
        }
```

Comment: What code throws that exception?

Comment: @Jasen Edited.

The exception is throw at the Repository injection

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

```
.AddTransient<DbContext, ApiDbContext>();
```

or

```
.AddTransient<ApiDbContext>();
```

Comment: Tried both, same exception